# Find all elements that appear together in certain contexts

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a database of restaurant reviews. I have three tables: `restaurant`, `user` and `review`.

A `restaurant` has N `reviews`, and a `user` has N `reviews`. As such, `review` contains the foreign keys `restaurant_id` and `author_id`. Each table has an `ID` attribute.

I would like to find the users that post together a lot. More specifically, I want to have a table with columns `user_A, user_B, reviewed_together` where `user_A` and `user_B` are two `user.IDs` and `reviewed_together` contains the count of all the restaurants in which there is a review by BOTH `user_A` and `user_B`.

I am a beginner in SQL and I'd like to learn how to handle these situations properly, so links to resources and a sketch to your thought process would be a huge help :-)

Comment: I recommend reading [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) on Relational Division. Your case is the simplest one with only 2 elements in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this query:

```
select r1.author_id as user_a, r2.author_id as user_b,
  count(r1.restaurant_id) as reviewed_together
from review r1 inner join review r2 on r1.restaurant_id = r2.restaurant_id
  and r1.author_id > r2.author_id
group by r1.author_id, r2.author_id
```

but be careful about the

```
r1.author_id > r2.author_id
```

part, because if you change this to <> (unequal) you will get duplicate records.

please try and tell me if this query gets you the correct results you want.

Comment: That's the query I wanted, thanks for the ">" sign, I didn't think about it. Took some time to understand why it works but yes, it does the job.

However, it is painfully slow on my dataset since it's `O(|r|²)`, where `|r|` is the number of reviews I have. How should I speed it up? I guess that creating the `r1 join r2` table would still take `O(|r|²)` so it doesn't look like the way to go here...

Comment: you are welcome, to speed up you can try indexes on review table. try (restaurant_id, author_id) index. also if this answer is useful please mark as accepted answer

Comment: They are connected by foreign key contraints so they are already indexes (innoDB)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this answer might not completely true but I can not use comments yet, so I will use answer to reply, clearify and so on.

My first logical trial is the code below, it seems fine but where condition. I am not sure about that, I can enhance it if you comment. Can you please try the code below, I couldn't try it as I don't have any data.

```
select UserA.UserID as USER_A, UserB.UserID as USER_B, count(restID) as COMMON_COMMENTS
from 
    (select distinct(userID),restID from reviews group by restID) UserA,
    (select distinct(userID),restID from reviews group by restID) UserB
where UserA.restID = UserB.restID
group by UserA.userID, userB.userID
```

Your comments will enhance this query, I hope.

Comment: you don't have restID columns in UserA and UserB subqueries.

Comment: still I think this query needs much work to be run without errors. distinct(userID) is not a correct way to use it. and using distinct with group by is also seems meaningless.